# What is the difference between DistributedCache.getCacheFiles() and DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles()

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

What I understood is

**DistributedCache.getCacheFiles()** in 
*distributed mode* 
and **DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles()** in *pseudo-distributed 
mode.*

So can we check if we are running in pseudomode or distributed mode in our MapReduce code

```
if(distributed)
 DistributedCache.getCacheFiles()
else
 DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles()
```

Can we do something like this or is there a better way.

And DistributedCache can take both *HDFS or local data* eventhough we are using **DistributedCache.getCacheFiles()** and **DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles()** in relative modes.